# Groovy:Xml: How to display Xml response in textarea of gsp page

Tags: xml, grails, groovy, gsp, xmldocument

Have an Xml response stored in a string, i want to display it in a textarea in gsp page

```
String responseXml = ""<Cars>
                           <Car>benz</Car>
                           <Car>audi</Car>
                           <Car>bmw</Car>
                       </Cars>""
```

in gsp page

```
<g:textArea name="xml" value="${responseXml}"  rows="20" cols="100"/>
```

getting response in textarea as a single line of xml tags like this

```
<Cars><Car>benz</Car><Car>audi</Car><Car>bmw</Car></Cars>
```

but what i want is display xml tags in textarea like this

```
<Cars>
   <Car>benz</Car>
   <Car>audi</Car>
   <Car>bmw</Car>
</Cars>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a taglib for this since I had this problem in muitiple places:

```
 /**
 * Preserves line breaks and spaces of the supplied value when displaying as html.
 * @param value - The value to preserve linebreaks of.
 */
def preserveFormat ={ attrs, body ->
    def value = attrs.value
    out << value.encodeAsHTML().replace('\n', '<br/>\n').replace(' ','&nbsp;').replace('\t','&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;')
 }

/**
 * Displays xml content in a pretty formatted way and preserves formatting in html view.
 */
def displayXml={attrs, body ->
    def xml = attrs.xml
    assert xml
    def prettyXml = groovy.xml.XmlUtil.serialize(xml)
    out << preserveFormat(value:prettyXml)
}
```

I updated my reply with an additional taglib that also formats xml in a pretty way according to suggestion in comments below.

Comment: Wouldn't this class (http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/xml/XmlUtil.html) be helpful?

Comment: It would absolutely be helpful if the xml is not already formatted in a pretty way. In that case it is better to format it with XmlUtil first. My taglib is used more generally for all type of text where I want to preserve the format in the html view.

Comment: Ok. I'd just add `XMlUtil`'s pretty printing to the tag You created to be always sure it'll work well.